# Grunt task styleguide styledocco

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Is there a way to include a .js file in the output generated by https://github.com/indieisaconcept/grunt-styleguide http://jacobrask.github.com/styledocco/ ?

I have a grunt task that compiles my CSS into an HTML file but I would also like to include a script with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to the [default template](https://github.com/indieisaconcept/grunt-styleguide/blob/master/templates/kss/index.html) or your own.

Comment: my use case is that people will download my CSS make modifications and view them all in the styleguide (so the styleguide is more like a dev dependency to view modifications and such). I found the answer day ago , you just have to add this to the Grunt task `options : { include: ['yourfile1.js','yourfile2.js'] }` after the part where you tell it which files to compile. Weirdly enough if you give it just one file to include that file will be included once for each of the files you actually compile (at least that's the behaviour i noticed)

Comment: That, I believe, applies to KSS, but not to styledocco.  styledocco not done through grunt has an --include param